# ExtJS 4 - Never cache tree nodes in tree panel

Tags: caching, extjs, extjs4, treenode, treepanel

I have a simple Ext.tree.Panel, which loads its data from a Ext.data.TreeStore using an ajax proxy.

The default behavior when expanding a treenode seems to be:

- if expanded before: retrieve from cache
- if never expanded: retrieve from server

How can I turn off the caching option, so that it **never** caches (i.e. always retrieve from server)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this as a listener in the store to get the desired behavior:

```
collapse: function(node){
    node.removeAll();
    node.set("loaded", false);
}
```

Comment: In newer versions of ExtJS' TreeStore (6.6 at the moment) this event is called `nodecollapse`